# Error while transferring database - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to transfer a mysql database to an older version of mysql, and after maybe 50th error, this one is where i dont know or can not find a solution to resolve it.

If anyone can help me it would be amazing!

```
> 6 errors were found during analysis.

> Unexpected character. (near "\" at position 26)
> Ending quote " was expected. (near "" at position 28)
> Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "so" at position 0)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "fr" at position 3)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "\" at position 26)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near """ at position 27)
SQL query:

> so.fr/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/\"

> MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'so.fr/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/\"' at line 1
[ Back ]
Open new phpMyAdmin window
```

Comment: Could you post the complete sql statement which is causing the error.

Comment: What came before that weird string?

Comment: Weirdly the problem is that it can not be compressed as zip but gz, and you need a faster upload speed so it does not stops the import process and continue again. Thanks.